# Extract the item and description from purchase text description using Python. Part of speech did not work :(

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, text-mining

Hi I hope you all are doing well. I'm currently working on a project which has descriptions about the purchase made. I have to extract the products and if the description is given that as well. I tried using parts of speech that did not give a good result. Example of data is as below:
"I bought a new xbox 360" - the output should be "xbox 360"
"Mayo Scissors: ROBOZ RS-6870 straight, 43mm blade length, length 5.5" - the output should be "Mayo Scissors 5.5' by Roboz"

Comment: Well, the things you want to extract are not parts of speech. There's your problem right there...

Comment: perhaps you should use named entity recognition (NER) instead

Comment: @alexis Do you have any other suggestions? I tried NER. It did not give output when I have data as shown in the second example.

Comment: @Marat Do you have any other suggestions? I tried NER. It did not give output when I have data as shown in the second example.

Comment: there are several dozen models for NER. Which ones did you try and what exactly didn't work?

Comment: Do you have a predetermined number of products? or are you looking to extract general products? If you have a predetermined number of products, you can use a rule based approach. If you want a model to detect products in general, then you need to use a NER model like @Marat said. There are many out of the box NER models for products but I highly doubt any of them will work with high accuracy out of the box for your use case. In my opinion, I think you will need to train a custom NER models for products.

Comment: @Marat I tried using NER to extract the organizations. It worked well. But it failed to detect the products like xbox, Scissors etc... 
I'm very new to NLP if there are certain models that you think could work. Please let me know. I will try that! Thank you for taking out time :)

Comment: @raqib No, there is no predetermined list. It can be anything! Yes, looking to extract products/purchases made.

Comment: It worth formulating a question like "I need to improve NER performance on a corpus that looks like that [examples of input data]. I tried this Stanford CRF NER (or whatever your model is), here is my code: [your code]. It doesn't recognize entities like [example]. What NER model will perform better on this data?".  It will be a lot easier to answer this way. It is better to post a new question than to recover this one.

Comment: Ashish, the examples you give are not pos-tagging, and they are not NER. I'd class it as some kind of entity resolution -- you already have a database of product names and you want to detect variant mentions of them. But that just describes the problem, not the solution.